# scanf for only ONE char

Tags: c++

I need to be able to detect extraneous input and exit my program.

If I input a string of more than 1 char into `scanf("%c", &var);` it takes the first letter and stores it into var but the programs continues.

I tried to use `if (scanf("%c", &var) != 1)` but it returns 1 every time no matter the input so its no difference.

I know other functions like fgets() may be better suited for this but I have been instructed to use the scanf() function.

How should I do this?

Comment: `if(scanf("%c%c", &var, &extra) == 2 && extra != '\n')`

Comment: Note that you're normally going to have at least a newline after the character that was entered, often more (unless the character is the newline).  You need to decide and explain what you're trying to do more precisely.  What has been entered before?  What has been entered after the character?  Are you sure you should be worried about it?  (The answer to this last one may be 'yes', but you need to be careful about what you're allowing and disallowing.)

Comment: Also note that in general, you should not tag a question with both C and C++. Choose the language you're learning and do not tag the question with the other.

Comment: did you tried `getchar()`?

Comment: @Antz -- note that OP stated: "I have been instructed to use the `scanf()` function."

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what it is that you are trying to do? What makes input extraneous exactly? Is it that it's on the same line? If you ask for one character and I type "ab", the "b" isn't necessarily extraneous -- it could be for something totally unrelated and you just shouldn't have read it.

Answer (score 1):

When reading user input scanf can take its input from a file, or the console.

When reading from the console, the data becomes available to the program only when a line break is added.  This means anything that was typed on the same line, is read.

Imagine I have a maze program, and it wants me to choose which way to go....

```
 while( !atGoalLocation() ) {
     printf( "Which direction (f)orward (l)eft (r)ight?\n" );
     scanf( "%c", &dir );
     processDirection( dir );
 }
```

I could either enter the route through the maze as

```
f
l
f
r
f
f
```

Or it may also be correct to enter my input as

```
flfrff
```

Depending on your task, they may mean the same thing.

If you want to allow either of these inputs, then make sure you eat the white space by adding " " to the scanf.

```
if( scanf( " %c", &dir ) == 1 )
```

If the line break version is the only method you want to accept, then you should separate the lines and then try the scan.

```
 char line[200];
 while( fgets( line, sizeof( line ), stdin ) != NULL ){
      sscanf( line, "%c", &dir );
```

Also for C++ we should be using the `std::cin` and `std::cout`.  However the same complications occur for unread characters on the same line, so I would still use a line based parser.

```
std::string line;
while( std::getline( std::cin, line ) ){
   // here we could parse the line using std::strstream to decode more complext things than a char.
   dir = line[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a space before the `%c`:

```
scanf(" %c",&var);
```

Answer (score -2):

And if you just dont want your program to wait for an enter after typing the character, use getch() defined in "conio.h"

```
c = getch();
```

OR

In scanf("%c",&var); you could add a newline character \n after %c in order to absorb the extra characters.

```
scanf("%c\n",&in);
```

Comment: `getch()` is **not** a standard function. It has two different versions in MS-DOS `conio.h` and Unix nCurses library.

Comment: Yes, the main aim was to solve the issue and I gave two ways that worked for me. I do not see the issue! @iBug